# Python('module' object is not callable )Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm getting this issue as mentioned in the title.
I'm trying to run a file to print hello world in the widget. I'm getting what I want when I run it in my system, but when I'm running it in colab its not working.

**Code:**

```
import tkinter

root = tk()

myLabel = Label(root, text="Hello World!")

myLabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-db74150bd164> in <module>()
      1 import tkinter
      2 
----> 3 root = tk()
      4 
      5 myLabel = Label(root, text="Hello World!")

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I tried changing `tk` into various forms(`Tk, tK, Tkinter, tKinter`), but it isn't working anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

When you see `Tk()`, it is an instance of `Tk()` class present in `__init__.py` file in `tkinter` folder.

Since you have imported tkinter, you have to specify `tkinter.Tk()`to create a instance of `Tk()`

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.tk()
myLabel = Label(root, text="Hello World!")
myLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

In some programs, you can also see `tk.Tk()`. This is because the module `tkinter` is imported as `tk`:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

See the source code of [`tkinter`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/tkinter)

At line 2273 in `__init__.py`, you can see:

```
class Tk(Misc, Wm):
    """Toplevel widget of Tk which represents mostly the main window
    of an application. It has an associated Tcl interpreter."""
    _w = '.'

    def __init__(self, screenName=None, baseName=None, className='Tk',
                 useTk=True, sync=False, use=None):

        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors:

```
import tkinter as tk 

root = tk.Tk() # tk() you can't call a module, write tk.Tk() instead.
myLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Hello World!") # add tk.
myLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just import tkinter as

```
    from tkinter import *
```

by using this it will work